# Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, createjs

I have installed externs for createjs libraries:

```
haxelib install createjs
```

I added the createjs library to compile file:

```
-main com.ketab.createjs_js_js.Main
-cp src
-lib createjs
-js bin/m.js
```

And I can compile with no errors, but in chrome, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined
```

for the line

```
createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
```

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>createjs_js_js</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="haxe:trace"></div>
    <script src="m.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504718/createjs-haxe-uncaught-referenceerror-createjs-is-not-defined ?

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341211/flashdevelop-haxe-import-createjs

Comment: No, as I have included the createjs library in compilation libraries, I think it has to do with HTML side, shall I include the original createjs library??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I have to add

```
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

in the HTML file, I thought that it will included within the compiled javascript file ..
I hope this will help some one ..